# Need a little guidance to make GUI calculator using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, calculator

I'm completely new in `WPF` but good familiar with `oop`, `generics` etc.. But i'm trying to make a calculator, have a look into

[image: SCREENSHOT]

where i get my approach by my own coding.

But the problem I'm little confused is how to get that value which is showed into textbox and do sum?

look into source:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Text;

namespace WpfCalculatorGUI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void nine(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DispBox.AppendText("9");

        }
    }
}
```

Please help with guidance.

Comment: In my opinion the best way to access control values in the UI in WPF is to use the MVVM pattern and data binding. There are many tutorials google "introduction to MVVM in WPF"

Comment: check out caliburn.micro for a great MVVM framework

Comment: What's the aim of `MVVM framework or architecture`?

Comment: It ties together the behaviour of your data, behaviour of your business logic and your presentation layer. Basically, taking your calculator as an example: you would probably have a `Calculator` class which modelled the functionality of a calculator (input/output), you would have a `CalculatorViewModel` which contained `ICommand` implementations in order to activate the calculator - commands such as `Input(int value)` or `Add()` or `Equals()` which would call the equivalent methods on the `Calculator` class. Finally you have your WPF app which binds to the `CalculatorViewModel`

Comment: The WPF pages (`Views`) use bindings to glue it all together - you may add a button in your XAML which has the value `1` in the middle of it. This button when pressed would bind to the `Input` command, passing the value `1` as a parameter. The binding would know how to call the `Input` method on the `ViewModel` and this would in turn call `Input` on your calculator and deal with notifying the user interface (via `INotifyPropertyChanged`) that the display needed updating. A textbox on your `View` would be bound to the `Result` on the `ViewModel` which got it's value from the `Calculator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper approach to this problem is to create MVVM architecture and use bindings. You have to read a lot more about that, because this is a very long topic.

A **halfway quick'n'dirty** solution might be to bind to the form itself:

```
<Window x:Name="rootControl" ...

<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=rootControl, Path=Display, Mode=TwoWay}" ...
```

And

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string display;

    // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged

    // This should be done by Commands, actually
    public void Nine(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Display += "9";
    }

    public string Display
    {
        get
        {
            return display;
        }
        set
        {
            display = value;
            if (NotifyPropertyChanged != null)
                NotifyPropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Display");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So firstly i would have to learn `MVVM architecture`?..i heard that name first time..

Comment: Well, learn about databinding to get the job done. You will want to go into MVVM after that.

Comment: MVVM (Model-View-Viewmodel) is prepared specially for WPF. The general rule is that if you will follow the MVVM architecture, WPF will help you on the way. But if you won't separate code from view, things will become more and more difficult to implement. Data binding is actually a part of MVVM, so you'll learn it on the way.

Comment: I might also add that it's wise to separate out the calculator and display logic - there should be a calculator class which deals with taking input, doing calculations and providing output. I realise this is only a contrived example but you should not add the value "9" directly to a text box - you should pass 9 to the calculator class which should do any internal updates/calculations and change it's `Result` value. The display update should be the concern of the `ViewModel` so any input commands should cause a new value to be got from the calculator. This will help create a cleaner solution

Comment: @Charleh Note the "halfway" word :) The funny thing with WPF is, that though it makes complicated things simple, it also makes simple things complicated - the simple calculator application would take like 3x amount of code required to write it in WinForms. I mean, there's nothing, what can be *fixed* in OP's code. It should be rewritten from scratch.

Comment: Not strictly true - if you wrote the app in WinForms I'd still advocate separation of concerns. You can't test a forms app without user interaction - a calculator is probably one of the most testable pieces of code you can write - and writing unit tests ensures that everything works (you can pretty much cover 100% of the code using unit tests for a calculator). The UI then just becomes an overlay for the input/output functions in the calculator. I'd use about the same amount of code with WPF/WinForms with the difference that the WPF code would be testable.

Comment: My point is - you would be better off writing 100% of the code *WITHOUT* the UI and test it **before adding** the UI. Writing the calculator into the UI is a bad idea. It might work, but you would have a really hard time testing it or using it in another project. This applies to both WinForms and WPF.

Answer (score -1):

Set Name="tb"(that's what I named my textbox) and add Click="Button_Click" to your 1,2,3,4,.... buttons 
then do this in .cs file to display clicked numerics in textbox

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        tb.Text += b.Content.ToString();
    }

 private void Result_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                result();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Receiving", exc.StackTrace);
                tb.Text = "Error!";
            }
        }

private void result()
        {
            String op;
            int iOp = 0;
            if (tb.Text.Contains("+"))
            {
                iOp = tb.Text.IndexOf("+");
            }
            else if (tb.Text.Contains("-"))
            {
                iOp = tb.Text.IndexOf("-");
            }
            else if (tb.Text.Contains("*"))
            {
                iOp = tb.Text.IndexOf("*");
            }
            else if (tb.Text.Contains("/"))
            {
                iOp = tb.Text.IndexOf("/");
            }
            else
            {
                tb.Text = "Error";
            }

            op = tb.Text.Substring(iOp, 1);
            double op1 = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text.Substring(0, iOp));
            double op2 = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text.Substring(iOp + 1, tb.Text.Length - iOp - 1));

            if (op == "+")
            {
                tb.Text += "=" + (op1 + op2);
            }
            else if (op == "-")
            {
                tb.Text += "=" + (op1 - op2);
            }
            else if (op == "*")
            {
                tb.Text += "=" + (op1 * op2);
            }
            else
            {
                tb.Text += "=" + (op1 / op2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: He already set the name to DispBox. Apart from that this is totally improper solution in WPF environment - MVVM should be used here along with databinding.

Comment: `Where did you come up with "tb" if you don't mind ?`

Comment: @Romiox I have just started to learn WPF and I know I have a lot to learn. I'm just telling what I did to implement Calculator a few days back :(

Comment: I understand.. :) but i'm confused bit ..how did you created an object to `tb` here.. that's what i'm asking :)

Comment: @VipulSharma Alright, sorry for the mean response. But you could use the same advice as OP then, and learn Databinding and MVVM to improve.

Comment: @nitingoyal set your textbox "Name" property to whatever you want, let it be DispBox, then replace tb -> Dispbox

Comment: @VipulSharma The problem is, that you wrote the calculator in total WindowsForms style, only using the WPF. There's no actual architecture to the program, no ViewModel, no bindings etc. If you'll follow this path, your code will become harder and harder to maintain. Don't make my mistake and read about MVVM *before* writing actual WPF code...

Comment: @Romiox Yeah sure I Will...!! Btw that's the other reason why I reponded to this question because I knew I am gonna learn something cool today, but instead I got -1.